# rollup.js how to import additional files without changing source files

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

my example is based on the rollup.js basic example: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#rolluprollup

the project i am working on require additional files to be included and excluded. (i know how to exclude path's using 'rollup-plugin-ignore' plugin.)

how can i tell rollup.js to add files to the import list (same as i was importing them in the source code), without changing the source files. ?

i tried to commonjs plugin

```
var commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
var include = ["D:\\...abs_path....\\components\\Auth\\FormLogin.jsx"]
commonjs( {"include": include})
```

but i don't see the 'FormLogin' component in the output file.

is there a more simple way, can you help me please ?

i will appreciate your help.
thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your question. You're more likely to get a response if you detail what research you took to try to find a solution.  Please see the Stack Overflow Question Guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i updated my question still haven't found solution for that thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats a little bit unorthodox because rollup.js uses tree-shaking to analyse your code and only include the used parts and you want something included which isnt used.

the easist way would be concatenation on the command line, like in windows cmd:

```
type file_from_rollup.js additional.js > bundle.js
```

second, you could instruct rollup to use two entry points:

```
rollup main.js libB.js -d ./bundle --format cjs
```

this will generate two bundled files in the ./bundle folder, both of them tree-shaked

If the FormLogin.jsx is referenced in the source code (seen from the main entry point) try to disable tree shaking like

```
rollup main.js --no-treeshake  --file bundle.js --format cjs
```

and see if its included. Maybe rollup.js doesnt recognize it corretly: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#tree-shaking-doesnt-seem-to-be-working

Comment: thank you @Marinus Pfund. you helped me validate my concerns. i need a single output file. since in both cases i am going to manipulate/merge files any way. i will generate a new source for getting a single output.